# Why the updated date doesn't get updated

Tags: python, evernote

I'm trying to compare the last updated time of a note, however whenever I use `note_store.updateNote(dev_token, note)` it doesn't seem to update the last updated time. In Evernote client, the note doesn't show as updated.

If I update it manually with `note.updated = int(time.time())*1000` then it works fine in the Evernote client, yet the next time I pull the note with `note_store.getNote(dev_token, guid, True, True, False, False)`, then `note.updated` is still set to its original creation date!

Is there any way to see what the last updated time is? Otherwise, there's no way to know whether the note has been updated or not..

Here's the raw info I get from the script, yet in the Evernote client I clearly see that note has a different update time:

```
NoteMetadata(updated=1477775369000, created=1477775369000, deleted=None, contentLength=None, title='backup.sh', notebookGuid=None, updateSequenceNum=None, tagGuids=['3b50966a-f7d9-4c5b-ad94-85a2750eed97'], largestResourceMime=None, attributes=NoteAttributes(lastEditorId=None, placeName=None, sourceURL=None, classifications=None, creatorId=None, author=None, reminderTime=None, altitude=None, reminderOrder=None, shareDate=None, reminderDoneTime=None, longitude=None, lastEditedBy=None, source=None, applicationData=None, sourceApplication=None, latitude=None, contentClass=None, subjectDate=None), guid='3cc67126-e44b-4af0-a88c-edb6535f71bb', largestResourceSize=None)
```

Comment: Doing an `updateNote` via the API does not alter the `updated` property; you have to manage it yourself. But what's odd is when you say the client shows your altered date but then a subsequent `getNote` does not. That makes no sense. What happens if you export the note to ENEX - does the `updated` property in the ENEX file show the original date or your adjusted one?

Comment: I found the issue but I think it's a bug. The 'updated' value of 'getNote' is fine, but 'noteMetadataResultSpec' is always set to the same as created date as shown above, even with 'includeUpdated=True'. So I need to fetch all of the full notes to see their updated dates, instead of just looking at metadata..

Comment: I'm able to get the correct `updated` values using `NotesMetadataResultSpec` in the C# API. It's possible it's a bug in the Python API, but try setting the following fields to `True` in your result spec and see if it makes any difference; this is what I'm using which works properly for me: includeTitle, includeAttributes, includeUpdated, includeNotebookGuid, includeUpdateSequenceNum, includeTagGuids. If that works, you can then try removing one of those at a time to see which might affect the `updated` value.